# Reference version string from another project using WiX

Tags: c#, .net, wix

Right now, in one of our WiX installers, we explicitly define the product version string like so:

```
<?define ProductVersion="1.2.3"?>
```

We also use this same version number in the title of another form, below is a very simplified example of how this is applied:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    // assume the designer code is all properly generated

    private const string VERSION = "1.2.3";

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text += string.Format(" v{0}", VERSION);
    }
}
```

This seems clunky and I feel it should be unnecessary to update our product version in two places. Where is the best place to store the version string information so I only have to update it in one place, and just reference this data from both the form and installer?

As a note, in this case the product version does not match the assembly version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you would like to go through as much trouble as my solution will require, but here is it:

First, you should store assembly version in AssemblyInfo.cs file. This will allow sharing version (and other company - specific info) between projects just by referencing a common AssemblyInfo in all your projects. You can do it by adding existing file to a project as a link. For example, all our projects have two AssemblyInfo files: one local, project specific (GUID, etc...), and one common, with version info and company name.

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.3.100.25")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.0")]
```

Second, if you have not done this already, take the WIX version out of WXS file and put it into a separate WXI file. Again, this will allow separate editing of version (and other constants, if needed), and referencing it in several projects:

```
<?include ..\..\..\Common\WIX\Version.wxi ?>
```

Then, you will have to write a build task for MSBuild, and incorporate it as a pre-build dependency for all projects. In the build task, you can take version number from WXI file and put it into AssemblyInfo file, or vice versa. You can even store version data in a separate XML and inject it into both WXI and AssemblyInfo. Reading and writing WXI and AssemblyInfo is a simple string manipulation in C#, do not bother yourself with Reflection and stuff.

This third step is the only required one, and the most difficult. You should probably do all this if you have a lot of projects, or using automated builds.

Comment: The best part is we already have the third step implemented :), except the version info is defined in our continuous integration setup. With some tweaks, I could probably set the version info in there as long as we set up a separate build project for the product I work. Don't know why I didn't think of this before

Answer (score 5):

C# doesn't have a preprocessor the way that C/C++ and the WiX toolset do, so you can't do the obvious thing and pass the version in via that route. If the product version matched the assembly *file* version, then you could do:

```
<Product Version='!(bind.fileVersion.FileIdOfAssembly)'>
```

That would be ideal if the file version could match. If not, then the only option left is to write something during install time and read it at run time. For example:

```
<RegistryValue Root='HKLM'
               Path='SOFTWARE\!(bind.property.Manufacturer)\!(bind.property.ProductName)'
               Name='Version' Value='!(bind.property.ProductVersion)' Type='string' />
```

Then read that registry key in your frmMain(). Not sure it's worth the extra complexity of the app, since you have the simple, robust solution right now.

Comment: So there's no way to define a variable in the assembly project itself that the both the WiX installer and the C# code I have can reference? Both solutions I've seen so far seem more complex than it ought to be.

Comment: For the .csproj, I believe you'd have to generate code to create a partial class or something. The .wixproj supports preprocessor variables so it's easy.

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if C# at least supported a few more preprocessor commands to reference data from other projects.

Comment: C# has Reflection, and getting executing assembly file version is easy:
`Assembly oAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
FileVersionInfo oFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(oAssembly.Location);
Console.WriteLine(oFileVersionInfo.ProductName);
Console.WriteLine(oFileVersionInfo.Comments);
Console.WriteLine(oFileVersionInfo.LegalCopyright);
Console.WriteLine("Version:" + oFileVersionInfo.FileVersion.ToString());`